# Python. Парсинг. Не находит тэги

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import xlsxwriter
import re
import time

url = 'https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--mobilnye-telefony/34512430/list?cvredirect=3&text=купить%20смартфон%20цена&hid=91491&allowCollapsing=1&local-offers-first=0'

# Создаем новый браузер
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--headless")

options.binary_location = 'C:\Chrone\chrome.exe'

service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager(version='102.0.5005.61').install())

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)

browser.get(url)  # Открываем страницу

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')  # создаем суп

time.sleep(5)
name = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "_1GfBD").text
print(name)
```

Не находит тэги. НИКАКИЕ. Представлена часть кода. Верхняя часть протестирована на другом сайте и работает. На этом никак. В чем может быть причина ?

Comment: отключите опцию "--headless",  увидите наглядно ))

Comment: А зачем создавать `Soup` если его не используешь ?

Comment: @Namerek, код длиннее. И он создавался для парсинга другого сайта и отлично работает. А вот на этом не хочет. Вот я часть вырезал.

Comment: @Сергей Ш, спасибо. Все нашел.